# Can anyone make this function of findMostOccurringString as transaction-less (view or pure)?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, mapping, library

I want to make a utility `contract` (or more precisely a `library`) that can calculate the mode (max occurring) string from the given array of strings.

Here's my approach for the same:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract CalculateStringsMode {

    mapping(string => uint256) public stringCountMapping;

    string public mode = "";

    function findMostOccurringString(string[] memory arr)
        public
        returns (string memory)
    {

        // string memory mode = "";

        uint256 maxCount = 0;

        uint256[] memory countList = new uint256[](arr.length);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            stringCountMapping[arr[i]] += 1;
        }

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            countList[i] = stringCountMapping[arr[i]];
        }

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < countList.length; i++) {
            if (countList[i] > maxCount) {
                maxCount = countList[i];
            }
        }

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (maxCount == stringCountMapping[arr[i]]) {
                mode = arr[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        return mode;
    }
}
```

So, if anyone can further modify this in a way to avoid the use of `mapping` or to make the function as **transaction-less** by making that of type `view` or `pure`, so that this contract can be converted or used in the form of a `library`, then I'll really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using this code

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract CalculateStringsMode {


function findMostOccurringString(string[] memory arr)
    public
    pure
    returns (string memory)
{
    
    string memory mode = "";

    uint256 maxCount = 0;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        uint256 count = getCount(arr,arr[i]);
        if(count>maxCount){
            maxCount=count;
            mode = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return mode;
}

function getCount(string[] memory arr,string memory element) private pure returns(uint256 count){
    for(uint256 i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(compareStrings(arr[i],element)){
            count++;
        }
    }
}

function compareStrings(string memory a, string memory b)
    private
    pure
    returns (bool)
{
    return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked((a))) ==
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked((b))));
}
```

}